# Spring Boot App not connection to Kafka with SSL

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to configure kafka in my application and I'm getting the following error.
Could you please help me?
Ref: https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.1/kafka/ssl.html

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

````
spring:
  application:
    name: application
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    ssl:
      trust-store-location: src/main/resources/kafka.client.truststore.jks
      trust-store-password: password
      trust-store-type: JKS
      key-store-location: src/main/resources/kafka.client.keystore.jks
      key-store-password: password
      key-store-type: JKS
      protocol: SSL

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false```

My consumer config

    package config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    private static String KAFKA_USER = "user";
    private static String KAFKA_PASSWORD = "password";

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "MATHEUS");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        props.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config", PlainLoginModule.class.getName() + " required username=\"" + KAFKA_USER + "\" password=\"" + KAFKA_PASSWORD + "\";");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
````

Comment: This solved my problem. https://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=4399